# PayPal is redirect to success page, but it's not making the money transaction (and no webhook or IPN notification)

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

it's some days that i am trying to solve a paypal issue. I'm working with the PayPal PHP SDK, my envoirment is a Linux Server (Ubuntu 16) with Php 7.2 installed and running Laravel 5.6.

I installed through composer the paypal php sdk and i integrated 'successfuly' in the code. When i try to run the code, i get back the link for make the payment (usually where u redirect the user) so it's working fine, no problem about the first request or api credential.

The problem is that, if you go to the pay link and i made the payment, it will redirect the payer to the success page of my website but i am not getting any transaction in my account (the buyer and the reciver) and also i am not getting any webhook or IPN notify (also like, user have to money or user profile is not verified, just nothing).

What i already tryed:

- switching on live api and try with real paypal profile, but i got the same issue. So this is not the problem. (on paypal sdk github someone has a problem on sandbox).
- Using a Laravel Packege (same issue).

This is my code (but i don't think the problem is this one):

```
$_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
'CLIENT_ID','SECRET'));
    $_api_context->setConfig(array(
        'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'sandbox'),
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG'
    ));


    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
    $item_1 = new Item();
    $item_1->setName('Item 1') /** item name **/
    ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setPrice('3'); /** unit price **/

    $item_list = new ItemList();
    $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));
    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setTotal('3');
    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($item_list)
        ->setDescription('Your transaction description');

    $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();

    $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl('https://XXXXXXX.ngrok.io/success') /** Specify return URL **/
    ->setCancelUrl('https://XXXXX.ngrok.io/error');

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('Sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));


    //dd($payment);
    try {
        $payment->create($_api_context);
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        dd($ex);

    }

    foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if ($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
            $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
            break;
        }
    }
    $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

    dd($redirect_url,$_api_context,$paypal,$paymentGateway,$approvalUrl,$payment->getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I tryed to sent money form sandbox account (personal) to the business account that own the api, and the ipn is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that will have the same problem, u should execute the payment after the user is redirected to your success page.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find where you set post request send your server to save your transactions.
Try like this way ..
code..

```
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                value: '{{$form_data->net_amount}}'
            }
            }]
        });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            console.log('data');
            console.log(data);
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            console.log(details);
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
            // Call your server to save the transaction
            return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                orderID: data.orderID,
                userDetail: details,
                bookingId: '{{$form_data->id}}',
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
            })
            }).then(function(){
                location.reload();
            });
        });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```